# Why does removing overflow: auto move all my elements to the header?

Tags: html, css

[image]
[image]

Here you can see before and after I removed overflow:auto from my .header css
The elements on my header all have float property if that matters.

Why does removing overflow:auto make the website messy? I looked up what it's for and it's supposed to be for automatically making a scrollbar, but that doesn't make sense in my case...

Header styles:

```
.header {
   
    padding-right: 0px; 
    padding-left: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    text-align: left;  
    overflow: auto;
    color: white; 
  }
 
 

  .header img {
  float:left;
  
  }

  .header nav {   
    font-family: 'joanna_mtregular';
    font-size:20px;
    color:#ffffff;
    float:left;
    padding-top:55px;
    padding-left:200px;
    word-spacing: 40px;
  }
```

Comment: Could you add the rest of the styles applied to the header element?

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: @tbjgolden I have just added them

Comment: I assume that by using that overflow you are no longer clearing the floats. Please show exactly where that style is applied and where you removed it, and which value overflow had before removing. You really shouldn't use `float` for layout purposes. It's hard to understand, especially in conjunction with other styles/properties.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect @caxap should probably avoid floats in that case, and use flexbox instead.

Comment: just add <div style="clear:both"></div> after .header nav (as a sibling). Or use :after to clear the floats (cleaner)